# My java code isn't compiling? help please?

Tags: java

my code below doesn't seem to be compiling, I seem to get 9 different errors, please can anyone take a look at my code by any chance and post the amendments which could make it run correctly? thanks

```
class MineFinderModel {
    public static int MINE_SQUARE = 10;
    public static int EMPTY_SQUARE = 0;

    int num_of_cols;
    int num_of_rows;
    int[][]
        the_minefield;

    public MineFinderModel(int n_cols, int n_rows) {
        num_of_rows = n_rows;
        num_of_cols = n_cols;
        the_minefield = new int[num_of_cols][num_of_rows];
    }

    public boolean addMine(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
        if (thisCol >= n_cols || thisRow >= n_rows)
            return false;
        if (the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow] == MINE_SQUARE)
            return false;
        the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow] = MINE_SQUARE;
        return true;
    }
    public int getValue(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
        if (thisCol >= n_cols || thisRow >= n_rows)
            return false;
        return the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow];
    }
    public void addMinesToCorners() {
        the_minefield[0][0] = MINE_SQUARE;
        the_minefield[0][n_rows - 1] = MINE_SQUARE;
        the_minefield[n_cols - 1][0] = MINE_SQUARE;
        the_minefield[n_cols - 1][n_rows - 1] = MINE_SQUARE;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what are those errors? HINT: - Check your variable declaration. You seem to be using the parameter names of your constructors everywhere, instead of the actual instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below edited code.

Your mistake was that the arguments defined in the constructor were being used as the class level variables which was wrong. the scope of the variables was incorrect.

Also in the method: getValue you expect it to return int and then in the second line of the method you are returning false which is Boolean, thus the compilation issue.

i have changed this to return 0 for the same.(check if the logic is undisturbed.)

i compiled it also.

```
class MineFinderModel {
    public static int MINE_SQUARE = 10;
    public static int EMPTY_SQUARE = 0;

    int num_of_cols;
    int num_of_rows;
    int[][] the_minefield;

    public MineFinderModel(int n_cols, int n_rows) {
        num_of_rows = n_rows;
        num_of_cols = n_cols;
        the_minefield = new int[num_of_cols][num_of_rows];
    }

    public boolean addMine(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
        if (thisCol >= num_of_cols || thisRow >= num_of_rows)
            return false;
        if (the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow] == MINE_SQUARE)
            return false;
        the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow] = MINE_SQUARE;
        return true;
    }

    public int getValue(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
        if (thisCol >= num_of_cols || thisRow >= num_of_rows)
            return 0;
        return the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow];
    }

    public void addMinesToCorners() {
        the_minefield[0][0] = MINE_SQUARE;
        the_minefield[0][num_of_rows - 1] = MINE_SQUARE;
        the_minefield[num_of_cols - 1][0] = MINE_SQUARE;
        the_minefield[num_of_cols - 1][num_of_rows - 1] = MINE_SQUARE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that this is an assignment, posting full code will not help him.

Comment: he has the logic, i just corrected his syntax error.

if the correction of the syntax was the assignment..then its a different story altogether

Comment: I agree, but he used the parameters for the constructor (n_cols, n_rows) as if they were class fields which is a common mistake, telling about this mechanism would help him better.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to look at:
1. You havent define `n_cols` and `n_rows` variables correctly. I guess you want to use `num_of_cols` and `num_of_rows` instead of `n_rows` and `n_cols`.
2. `getValue` function suppose to return int.
3. Dont you have Eclipse or any other IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `n_cols` and `n_rows` in your `addMine`, `getValue`, `addMinesToCorners` methods use `num_of_rows`, `num_of_cols`. because `n_rows` and `n_rows` are not accessible in your other methods.

One more thing is that in your following method you must return `int` instead of `boolean`

```
public int getValue(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
    if (thisCol >= num_of_cols || thisRow >= num_of_rows)
        return false; //you should return int here
    return the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow];
}
```